# How to apply search filter on list in angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I want to implement search filter on data list which is stored in array and I want to apply search filter same like search in data table. as shown in below image.
but in that fields(name,address..etc) are not fixed.

[image: based on search textbox value apply filter on below data]

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/RQOk2EYS6TcYX52JTO69)**

if you want to filter by other fields just add them in the pipe:

```
import { Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], criteria: any): any {

        return items.filter(item =>{
           for (let key in item ) {
             if((""+item[key]).toLocaleLowerCase().includes(criteria.toLocaleLowerCase())){
                return true;
             }
           }
           return false;
        });
    }
}

    @Component({
      selector: 'sites-component',
      template: `
        <input #search  (keyup)="0">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let site of (sites | searchFilter: search.value )">(...)</li>
        </ul>
      `
    })
    export class SitesComponent{
       sites : Array;
    }
```

dont't forget to declare the pipe in your module.

Comment: I think this pipe only allow filter by "name" but I also want to allow filter by address or contact_no and so on.

Comment: @VedTest ok wait

Comment: Thanks for your quick help but as I mention in question that these fields are not fixed these will be change dynamically based on user section.

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine I'm getting PipeTransform is not defined, though I imported the module both in my main module and component. Can you please help with it?

Comment: `import { Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';` did you do this ?

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine Yes I did. Tried to create a plunker example, but it's not even loaded. Can you check please?
https://embed.plnkr.co/OGwuq9yhMkHUbK9wjmj1/

Comment: can u explain this line plz if((""+item[key]).includes(criteria)){
                return true;
             }

Comment: @UsmanIqbal convert `item[key]` to string using `""+item[key]` and check if string `""+item[key]` includes `criteria`

Comment: what is criteria here i searched in pipes docs i found nothing

Comment: and whats is includes here

Comment: criteria holds the value of `search.value` passed in the pipe you can change its name if you want. and `includes` is a javascript function see here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Comment: This wont work for case insensitive characters. If ""+item[key] is to be converted in lower case, how would we accomplish that? For eg, in your case, 'site' will yield the result but 'Site', wont.